# WndProc not being executed in User Control

Tags: vb.net

I have a user control that contains a textbox, which is used for Passwords, and a button next to the textbox for unmasking the password.

I previously asked this question when the text box was in a Form and the WndProc code works fine.
However, in the UserControl it seems to be ignored. The remainder of the code is for the associated button events.

Why doesn't the wndproc code execute?  I am sure I am missing something but do not know what.

The code is as follows:

```
Friend WithEvents txtPassword As TextBox
Friend WithEvents btnMaskButton As Button
Friend WithEvents ToolTip1 As ToolTip
Const EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP = &H1503

Private Sub txtPassword_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtPassword.KeyDown
    If (e.Modifiers = Keys.Control) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtPassword_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtPassword.KeyUp
    Dim PasswordMasked As PwdMaskStatus = DirectCast(txtPassword.Tag, PwdMaskStatus)
    Dim CtrlMsg As String = "Password Shortcuts Disabled"
    Dim CtrlCmds() As Keys = {Keys.Control Or Keys.C, Keys.Control Or Keys.Insert,
                              Keys.Control Or Keys.X, Keys.Shift Or Keys.Delete,
                              Keys.Control Or Keys.V, Keys.Shift Or Keys.Insert,
                              Keys.Control Or Keys.A}
    For Each CtrlKey As Keys In CtrlCmds
        If (e.KeyData = CtrlKey) Then
            e.Handled = True
            ToolTip1.Show(CtrlMsg, Me, New Point(0, Me.Height + 2), 6000)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(txtPassword, "Password")
End Sub

Private Sub txtPassword_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPassword.SizeChanged
    Dim ButtonY As Integer

    ButtonY = CInt((txtPassword.Height / 2) - (btnMaskButton.Height / 2) + 0.5)
    btnMaskButton.Location = New Point(btnMaskButton.Location.X, ButtonY)
End Sub

Private Sub txtPassword_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs)
    If CheckEmpty(txtPassword.Text) Then
        Call HidePassword()
        e.Cancel = True
    Else
        e.Cancel = False
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If (m.Msg = EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP) Then
        m.Result = IntPtr.Zero
        Return
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

Comment: Use a custom control derived from TextBox and override its WndProc. You can build it as part of the UserControl (*inside* the UC class) or a stand-alone class in a UserControl project (the latter is better, you have a reusable control you can add to any other project when needed).

Comment: Thanks Jimi.  I'll make a custom textbox with some other features and use it in the UserControl instaed of the standard Textbox.